# Shopping system using Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Iam learning symfony and I want to build a shop system for my school project. I want to send the list of items that the user select to another controller i don't know how.

here is my ShowItemAction

```
public function ShowItemAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('search', 'textbox', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'label' => false
            )))->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if (($form->isSubmitted()) && ($form->isValid())) {
        $formdata = $request->request->get('form');
        $search = $formdata['search'];
        $products_Repo = $em->getRepository('MyShopBundle:Products')->GetProducts($search);
        return $this->render('MyShopBundle:Products:show.html.twig',array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'products'=> $products_Repo
        ));
    }

    return $this->render('MyShopBundle:Products:show.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));

}
```

and my show.html.Twig

```
{% block body%}
<div id="cart-content">

</div>
    <div class="cart-buttons">
    <button id="cart">View Shopping Cart</button>
    <button id="clear-cart">Clear Cart</button>
</div>

{{ form(form) }}

{% if products is defined %}
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Partner-Name</th>
            <th>ProductNr</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for product in products %}
            <tr>
                <td><div class="partner">{{product.partner}}</div></td>
                <td><div class="partnerdata" data-value="{{ product.id }}">{{ product.productnr }}</div></td>
                <td><div class="description"> {{ product.description }}</div></td>
                <td><div class="price">{{ product.price }}</div></td>
                <td class="counter"><input type="number" name="count" min="1" step="1"></td>
                <td class="cart">
                    <button type='submit'>in den Warenkorb</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

my javascript:

```
 $('.cart').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var closestTr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var ref = closestTr.find('.partner').text();
        var data_value = closestTr.find('.partnerdata').data('value');
        var productNr=    closestTr.find('.partnerdata').html();
        var price= closestTr.find('.price').html();
        var count = closestTr.find('input').val();
        if (count < 1) {
        }
        else {
            $(".cart-content").prepend(HS_ref + "|" + data_value + "|" + herstellerNr + "|" + count + "|" + vk);
        }
    });
```

I can see the data which the user has selected(inside `<div id="cart-content"></div>`) but I don't know how to send those contents perhaps as a POST to the controller.

Something like this:   https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/shopping-cart-in-php.html

I am working on Symfony 2.7

Comment: With ajax you can send easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

First, you need to get the html data

Second, you have to send this data to the controller

Third, you have to get the data in the controller

### Here is an example :

**First** *"you need to get the html data"*

**HTML :**

```
<div id="cart-content" data-route="{{ path('get_user_card_items') }}">
    <span data-item-id="item1" data-quantity="2"></span>
    <span data-item-id="item2" data-quantity="1"></span>
    <span data-item-id="item3" data-quantity="5"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
/**
 * Get the content of #cart-content
 */
function getCartItems() {

    var items = [];
    $('#cart-content span').each(function(){ // loop into all span
        var item = { // create an item object who get all the data
            'id' : $(this).attr('data-item-id'),
            'quantity' : $(this).attr('data-quantity'),
        }
        items.push(item); // push into an array
    });

    return items;
}
```

**Second** *"you have to send this data to the controller"*

**JS**

```
function sendCartItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#cart-content').attr('data-route'), // here is a route variable
        method: 'POST',
        data: {items: getCartItems()},
        success: function (data) {
            // do some stuff when it's send
        }
    });
}
```

**Third** "*you have to get the data in the controller*"

**CustomController.php**

```
class CustomController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/getUserCardItems",  name="get_user_card_items")
     */
    public function getUserCardItemsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $items = $request->get('items');
        var_dump($items);die; // display for you the items to see if it's works (look into the networks console tab on google chrome)
       // some stuff like sending items to database...
    }
}
```

[Access network tab google chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)

And you done ;)

Comment: okay thanks I got the data inside the controller... But i want to redirect to the different page when with the data that the user selected if he clicks on "View shopping cart"

Comment: just use render function with this data. Or save into entities to keep it into database and display it.

Comment: The most easily is when a user click on add Card, you send this item to a Controller who save this in UserCard Entities and in the Card template, you just get the data

Comment: okay I think I will save to a database that way if the user logs in then he see his previous cart items.. Thanks for the help :)